# How do I bind to one data source but update trigger from another?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, triggers

I have a **TextBox** with a **OneWay** binding to a string property, and I'd like it to update when some *other* property on my **DataContext** changes.  My **DataContext** is an **ObservableCollection** and the **TextBox** displays statistics about the collection.  So I want the statistics to be updated whenever the collection changes, but I don't want to have to raise a dummy "statistics changed" event.

In other words, does XAML (or databinding generally) allow me to specify one binding for the data of a control and another for its update event?

Comment: if you do not want to raise the property changed for the property used in the binding, you could maybe use a `MultiBinding` and set both to be Binding properties within it and mention your UpdateTrigger accordingly as you require, in the converter / string-format just apply the first Binding's value to the result(first Binding being the statistics)? `Binding.StringFormat` should be better as you can then avoid a custom converter and do it just in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, there is a much easier way to achieve what you want:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Items} />

<TextBox Text="{Binding Items/PropertyName}" />
```

Assuming that your `ObservableCollection` has a bindable property named `PropertyName` in it and that your view model (or `DataContext`) has a property called `Items` of the type of your `ObservableCollection`, then the `TextBox` control will display the `PropertyName` value of the currently selected item in the collection.

You can find out more about the '/' path syntax from the [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: The question states _display statistics about the collection_. To me, at least, that implies he wants properties of the collection itself

Comment: @Jim, you might want to re-read my answer... particularly the line that says '*Assuming that your ObservableCollection has a bindable property named PropertyName in it*'.

Comment: Properties of the collection, not properties of the current item. So if I want to look at the size of collection is, I need to bind to `{Binding Items.Count, Mode=OneWay}`. `Items/PropertyName` looks for `PropertyName` on say `Person` class. It doesn't look for a property on `ObservableCollection`

Comment: I found that merely specifying "**{Binding Path=Playlist.Statistics, Mode=OneWay}**" achieved my result.  It appears that referencing "Playlist" (the **ObservableCollection**) causes an update to ALL dependent properties of the collection when the "collection changed" event occurs.  My **Statistics** property ("get" only) returns a pretty-printed string of useful information.

Comment: Now, my deeper question is this. When part of the binding **Path** is a **DependencyObject** or an **INotifyPropertyChanged**, does this imply that all dependent bindings will be reevaluated?

Comment: For objects that are not **ObservableCollection**, the best solution so far is **IValueConverter**.  Triggering on any property in an INPC object, a crafty converter can supply any string or value desired in any location.  In effect, it's a *lambda* to generate the bound value, which would be truly wonderful.

Comment: @Jim, ohhhhhhhhh... I see what you mean. Apologies, point taken and accepted.

Comment: @dhovel if you have solved your problem independently you should write an answer and accept it.